# Android spinner/sqlite database - getting cursor position not contents!

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

So my setup is that I have a database with two tables. My main input class is a basic form which has a spinner to select a category. Category is the second table, the spinner is powered by this database table and the main table has a foreign key of this table.

I have the spinner populating correctly etc but when storing the selected item from the spinner it is storing the cursor position which looks like:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@435b9ba0.
```

rather than the actual contents of it which should be the name from the database. The code I am using is:

```
String fkstring = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

If anyone could let me know how to solve this that would be great.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? still can't solve this and it has really halted development :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.getString(0)` to get a string, `.getString(0)` will get the first column `.getString(1)` the second etc etc.

`String fkstring = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().getString(0);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with this I get: The method getString(int) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: sorry i thought that the mSpinner was a cursor? What is your code for the getSelectedItem or is it inbuilt?

Comment: Get selected item is built in. My declaration for mSpinner is:  mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCat); - maybe it should be cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Try `String fkstring = (String) mSpinner.getSelectedItem();`